# How to run a ls on a s3 bucket that has acl enabled

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I have created an IAM role and attached it to an instance, would like anyone who logs into this instance to be able to upload, download and list the files in an s3 bucket with ACL enabled. mv and cp works but with aws s3 ls I get an error: A client error (AccessDenied) occurred when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied
I am guessing there is something wrong with the way I use the ls command (since we now have ACL enabled). My IAM policy is below, can someone please shed some light on this? Thank you

```
{ 
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "statement1",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ListBucket` permission needs to be specified on the actual bucket itself, and not the items inside of it.

You'll need to create two separate `Statements` in your IAM policy: one which applies to the bucket itself (`s3:ListBucket`) and another which applies to the items inside the bucket only (`s3:*`).

Structure your IAM policy like so:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1"],
      "Condition": {
          "StringEquals": {
              "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
          }
       }
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:*"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1/*"],
      "Condition": {
          "StringEquals": {
              "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
          }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

See [this page in the AWS documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-how-to-grant-access-to-an-amazon-s3-bucket/) for a related example.

Comment: Thank you, I created an IAM policy and attached the IAM role to an instance, now ls and cp work with and without the --acl bucket-owner-full-control. But mv fails with this error: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the DeleteObject operation: Access Denied
I made sure to also add s3:DeleteObject for the bucket itself

Comment: Do let us know what you ended up doing to resolve this, thanks!